# cPickle.dump always dumping at end of file

Tags: python, pickle

`cPickle.dump(object,file)` always dumps at the end of the file. Is there a way to dump at specific position in the file? I expected the following snippet to work

```
file = open("test","ab")
file.seek(50,0)
cPickle.dump(object, file)
file.close()
```

However, the above snippet dumps the object at the end of the file (assume file already contains 1000 chars), no matter where I seek the file pointer to.

Comment: On a side note, you should use `with` to open your files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be more of a problem with how you open the file than with `cPickle`.
`ab` mode, besides being an append mode (which should bear no relevance, since you `seek`), provides the `O_TRUNC` flag to the low-level `open` syscall. If you don't want truncation, you should try the `r+` mode.

If this doesn't solve yout problem and your objects are not very large, you can still use [`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps):

```
file = open("test","ab")
file.seek(50,0)
dumped= cPickle.dumps(object)
file.write(dumped)
file.close()
```

Comment: What's the issue with large objects? In fact, objects in my case will indeed be very large.

Comment: @Shobhit The problem would be if you were dealing with objects that, when pickled, were larger than your RAM, as you're storing the pickle result in memory instead of the disk

Comment: @Shobhit By the way, I cannot reproduce your problem on plain `open(...,'wb')`. Are you sure you should be opening the file with `a` flag? `wb` seems to write in right place - but it truncates, which may not be what you want. If you don't want to truncate, you should use `r+` instead

Comment: Opening in 'wb' mode overwrites the existing file (clears everything already present in the file). I do not want this. So, I have to use the 'a' mode.

Comment: Yes, r+ worked fine. Wasted so many hours because of opening the file in wrong mode